# polymer paper-menu-button dropdown doesn't work

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, tabs, icons, polymer

I am using polymer 0.5.5 and this is my code:

```
<paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="0" selectedindex="0"  id="paper-tabs" >

<paper-tab id="kids-tab" active>Kids</paper-tab>
<paper-tab id="raspberry-tab">Toony</paper-tab>
<paper-tab id="store-tab">Store</paper-tab>
<paper-tab id="schedule-tab">Schedule</paper-tab>

<paper-menu-button id="menuBtn" noink>
  <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" noink></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" halign="right">
    <core-menu class="menu">
      <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Feedback</paper-item>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-menu-button>
```

The dropdown does not work. I import all the required files but the problem persits

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure of your imports, can you try the following ?

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="drop down btn">
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" halign="right">
    <core-menu class="menu">
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Feedback</paper-item>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: it works but the droopdown is very small because it's into a paper-tabs.